# Как сделать элемент sticky если у его родителя absolute?

Tags: html, css, css3, sticky, absolute

У родителя `position: absolute`, можно ли у дочернего элемента сделать `position: sticky`?

У меня не получается, как можно найти выход?

Comment: Лучше нарисуйте, что хотите получить.

Comment: https://codepen.io/mars1k12/pen/wvGKqYm

Answer (score 5):

Это достаточно просто сделать, никаких особых техник тут не требуется:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sticky"></div>
  Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups. Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups. Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups. Lorem ipsum is placeholder text used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
```

Comment: Почему это не работает?   https://codepen.io/mars1k12/pen/wvGKqYm

Comment: Получилось, смотрите в codepen